# What is wrong with my code? I seem to be having local/global variable issues. Please help me

Tags: java, android

Here is my code (I have removed my import declarations to save space in the post):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1; // The request code
    Uri numToCall;
    String telAdded;

    public void Call(View view) {

        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            Uri numToCall = Uri.parse(telAdded);
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, numToCall);
            startActivity(callIntent);
        } else {
            Uri numToCall = Uri.parse(telAdded);
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, numToCall);
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }

    }

    public void openContacts(View view) {
        Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
        pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only
                                                        // contacts w/ phone
                                                        // numbers
        startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            if (uri != null) {
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    c = getContentResolver()
                            .query(uri,
                                    new String[] {
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                                    null, null, null);

                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String number = c.getString(0);
                        int type = c.getInt(1);
                        showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                        String telAdded = "tel:" + number;
                        Log.i("Value of telAdded", telAdded);

                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to call the number that gets chosen from the Contacts screen on the user phone but since the variable telAdded is declared within the onActivityForResult() method I'm not able to use it within the call method. How do I make the telAdded method global in scope so I can use it everywhere in my class? I even made it a field variable but no luck. When I try pressing the call button I have chosen a contact, my app just crashes.

LogCat errors:

```
12-26 15:47:52.420: I/Value of telAdded(23307): tel:7043809866
12-26 15:47:53.541: W/dalvikvm(23307): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41849e00)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307): Process: com.example.callnumber, PID: 23307
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3856)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4466)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18634)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5851)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:883)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3851)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    ... 11 more
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:160)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    at com.example.callnumber.MainActivity.Call(MainActivity.java:76)
12-26 15:47:53.551: E/AndroidRuntime(23307):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a **minimal** example.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I've reduced it as much as I can. Can you please help me?

Comment: Can we have a crash log from logcat?

Comment: @Houseman Of course. I'm on it.

Comment: @user3131263: I'd estimate that 90% of the code above is irrelevant to the current problem.  I would strip out everything that isn't directly relevant to the fact that you have a variable redeclared inside a method, or whatever.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The problem is the String variable "telAdded"

Comment: The problem has been fixed guys thanks to Henry!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set `telAdded` in `onActivityResult` you need to leave out the type. Otherwise you declare a local variable that hides the class field:

```
telAdded = "tel:" + number;
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! I've been fumbling around with this error for 3 days when all I had to do was delete ONE step. THANK YOU SO MUCH HENRY!! Could you please explain to me how adding the type made it a local variable?

Comment: `type var = val;` is a variable declaration with initializer, `var = val;` is an assignment according to the Java syntax.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for explaining it. You rock man you just made my day honestly!

Comment: I gave you a check btw.